# Laravel MassAssignmentException from firstOrNew by id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mass-assignment

I am attempting to save data using Laravel's `firstOrNew` method, which is producing a `MassAssignmentException` error.

I don't understand why the `firstOrNew` method should trigger a mass assignment exception since it is merely **looking** at the database, not attempting to save anything. From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#other-creation-methods):

> The firstOrNew method, like firstOrCreate will attempt to locate a
>   record in the database matching the given attributes. However, if a
>   model is not found, a new model instance will be returned. Note that
>   the model returned by firstOrNew has not yet been persisted to the
>   database.

Why then, should my code be throwing a MAE:

```
$tour = Tour::firstOrNew(array('id' => $this->request['id']));
```

As I understand, all that the above code is saying is basically "look and see if there is a row in the database with that ID, if so then return the row, if not, then create a new object with the relevant properties". It isn't saving any data so what is the problem?

Note that the error only occurs if the row doesn't exist.

Comment: You're trying to create an object by using an ID. This might be fine in your case, but usually ID's auto increment, so you wouldn't want to create a specific one. I'd firstOrNew an object by another attribute – if the name exists grab it, otherwise create one with that name. Also you could think about looking into findOrFail which sounds more suitable https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#retrieving-single-models – does an object with this ID exist? If so get, it, otherwise throw an exception

Comment: Thanks, although `findOrFail` probably isn't suitable since according to the docs it sends a 404 automatically, which I don't want. ID is indeed auto incrementing and is the only column guaranteed to be unique which is I why I wanted to use it. Not sure how to do this then....

Comment: Yeah I hear you. Alexey Mezenin's answer covers all the reasons why its failing. If you wanted an easy ride I'm pretty sure `$tour = Tour::find($this->request['id']); if( ! $tour) $tour = new Tour;` would be a really pain free way of getting to the same place. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, that would be a quick solution. I think I'm going to also implement a randomly generated UID column in my tables in addition to auto-incementing ID though, as I can see this problem cropping up again. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`firstOrNew()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Builder.php#L237) uses [`newInstance()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L495) which creates new model using constructor. [Constructor uses `fill()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L289) method which is Mass Assigment. That's why you're getting an exception.

So, you need to set `$fillable` array to use `firstOrNew()`

Comment: Ah, OK. *Constructor uses fill() method which is Mass Assigment.* That's the key there I guess.

Answer (score 1):

MassAssignmentException occurs when you do not have fillable or guarded fields defined in the Model

```
$guarded = [];
$fillable = ['explicitlydefinedfield'];
```

PS: you have copied the text which says exactly what is happening... it did not find the record and is trying to create a new one.

firstOrNew ... NEW

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of setting the `guarded` and `fillable` attributes, I just don't understand why they are necessary when data is not being 'persisted' (ie. saved) to the database

Comment: I think the next answer addressed that better :)